# Real open source cross-platform toolkit for mobile developing

Tags: android, ios, qt, cordova, appcelerator

I'm looking for open source real cross-platform toolkit for mobile developing which makes build & developing process elegant (write once compile anywhere) just like cross-platform desktop toolkit ([Qt](https://qt-project.org/), GTK+ or wxWidget).

I'm currently investigating in this list but I need your practical experiences or suggestions because all of them uses HTML5 somehow and I don't have much experience in HTML5/Javascript.

- [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/)
- [Appcelerator Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/platform/titanium-platform/)
- [Kurogo](http://kurogo.org/)

*PS*

[Qt toolkit](https://qt-project.org/) definitely fits my needs (supports native UI & real cross-platform) but until now they didn't release Android/iOS support they planned to after 6 months from now so I need a rapid solution until that date.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Codename One: [http://www.codenameone.com](http://www.codenameone.com/) you write the app and deploy it on different platforms, natively, including iOS.

Comment: As mentioned from [their website](http://www.codenameone.com/codename-one-build-server.html) I need to build my applications remotely! If that so, this is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

LiveCode seems quite versatile. I haven't used it myself but thinking about it. They have a comparison chart of what features are cross-platform [here](http://www.runrev.com/products/Overview/). It includes Android and iOS. But no mention of Mozilla's upcoming mobile OS or any others

Comment: LiveCode isn't open source solution